# Kafka Zookeper - not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)

Tags: apache-kafka, sasl

Getting below when trying to connect to zookeeper url using java
.Any pointers will be helpful

```
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,482 [main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Verifying properties
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,697 [main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property auto.offset.reset is overridden to smallest
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,698 [main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property auto.commit.interval.ms is overridden to 1000
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,698 [main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property group.id is overridden to n_secondary
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,698 [main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to xxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,xxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,xxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,698 [main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property zookeeper.session.timeout.ms is overridden to 6400
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,698 [main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property consumer.timeout.ms is overridden to 30
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,699 [main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Property zookeeper.sync.time.ms is overridden to 2000
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,728 [main] kafka.consumer.ZookeeperConsumerConnector  - [n__secondary_xxx-xxx--0001.xxxx.wxxxx.net-1491944854725-7865dd0f], Connecting to zookeeper instance at xxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,xxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,xxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,910 [ZkClient-EventThread-19-xxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,xxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,xxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667] org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread  - Starting ZkClient event thread.
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.8--1, built on 02/06/2016 03:18 GMT
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:host.name=ncl-sna-0001.corp.wayport.net
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_121
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.121-0.b13.el6_8.x86_64/jre
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.class.path=/opt//Scripts/consumer/ConsumerKafka.jar
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.library.path=/opt//////linux2x86/lib64:/opt/////linux2x86/lib64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:java.compiler=<NA>
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:os.name=Linux
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:os.arch=amd64
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-642.15.1.el6.x86_64
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,923 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:user.name=n_
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,924 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:user.home=/var/home/n_
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,924 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Client environment:user.dir=/opt////
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,927 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Initiating client connection, connectString=xxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,xxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,xxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667 sessionTimeout=6400 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@7e0b85f9
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,964 [main] org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient  - Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:34,969 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server xxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667/xxx.xxx.xxx.2xx:6667. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:35,072 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to xxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667/xxx.xxx.xxx.2xx:6667, initiating session
WARN    2017-04-11 21:07:36,401 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2137ms for sessionid 0x0
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:36,401 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2137ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:36,707 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to xxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667/xxx.xxx.xxx.2xx:6667. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:36,717 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to xxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667/xxx.xxx.xxx.2xx:6667, initiating session
WARN    2017-04-11 21:07:37,208 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2136ms for sessionid 0x0
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:37,209 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2136ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:38,227 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to serverxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667/xxx.xxx.xxx.2xx:6667. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:38,238 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to xxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667/xxx.xxx.xxx.2xx:6667, initiating session
WARN    2017-04-11 21:07:38,852 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2135ms for sessionid 0x0
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:38,852 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2135ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:39,809 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server xxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667/xxx.xxx.xxx.2xx:6667. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:39,820 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to xxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667/xxx.xxx.xxx.2xx:6667, initiating session
WARN    2017-04-11 21:07:40,374 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2135ms for sessionid 0x0
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:40,374 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2135ms for sessionid 0x0, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:40,545 [ZkClient-EventThread-19-hxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,hxxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667] org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread  - Terminate ZkClient event thread.
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:41,318 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Opening socket connection to server hxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6667. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:41,329 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Socket connection established to hak-dal-0002.corp.wayport.net/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:6667, initiating session
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:41,365 [ZkClient-EventThread-19-hxxx-xxx-0001.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667hxxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667,hxxx-xxx-0003.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667] org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread  - Terminate ZkClient event thread.
WARN    2017-04-11 21:07:41,954 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2134ms for sessionid 0x0
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:42,061 [main] org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper  - Session: 0x0 closed
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:42,068 [main-EventThread] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - EventThread shut down for session: 0x0
INFO    2017-04-11 21:07:43,319 [main] kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties  - Verifying properties
WARN    2017-04-11 21:07:43,465 [main-SendThread(hxxx-xxx-0002.xxxx.xxxx.net:6667)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  - Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 2136ms for sessionid 0x0
```

My Concern is what does this "Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) " means ?
Is this an issue .If so how this can be resolved?

Thanks and Regards
Jinesh Luke

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by clustering zookeeper